Автоматическая замена тревоги
Есть вопрос,
(текст оставлю тут, если вопрос удалится)

Ретрансляция в питон
Добрый день мне дали задание изучить ретрансляцию и сделать так взять прямые эфиры телеканалов и поставить на свой на питон как этого
сделать где искать что изучить я вообще не понимаю дайте направление

при проверке я поставила дубликат тревогу, но потом пораздумав пару секунд, отозвала тревогу, решила, что это не дубликат. И надо по другому отметить, или написать участнику комментарий.
Я отозвала тревогу, но моя тревога автоматически заменилась на необходимо улучшить

Это норма ? Так задумано ? (если да)Можно пояснить алгоритм ?

страницу я обновляла, потому что я подумала, что это как в одном из ранее вопросах про "побледневший аудит", просто осталось в памяти, но и при обновлении страницы было так же два пункта красным/серым, из которых первый не мною выбранный


Вам бы накопить репутации, вы вроде давно с нами, тогда можно будет нормально голосовать за закрытие, а не тревоги ставить, привлекая модераторов туда, где они по факту далеко не всегда нужны.

@aepot если не нужны, тогда зачем это меню изначально ?

на счет репутации (мне ставят два минуса в 5 минут (интересное совпадение, просто поэтому этот случай запомнился. напомню, на вопросе не было активности, он не был в топике, это был старый вопрос с моим и вашим ответом), на старом забытом вопросе на мой ответ, сразу после вашего комментария, там)))) на котором стояли два плюса, от кого то, кому мой ответ был полезен. Я не бегу за репутацией, да и вопрос не о том, что надо, а вопрос о том, что есть )))

@aepot не все тревоги улетают сразу к модераторам. Тревоги по закрытие улетают в очередь для обработки обычными участниками с доступом к соответствующим очередям.

@αλεχολυτ а зачем тег "локализация" ?

Потому что затрагивает и переводы в том числе. Кстати, он уже подхватился.

Тревоги "Необходимо улучишь" и "Дубликат" относятся к одной группе тревог. Назовём эту группу "рекомендация к закрытию". Например, если выбрать "Необходимо улучшить", то в подменю так же будет присутствовать вариант "дубликат", как и несколько других вариантов, например, "требуется уточнить подробности" или "основано на мнениях". Также можно заметить, что если уже взведена  одна из этих двух тревог, то вторую поставить нельзя. Другие тревоги, например, "Спам" или "Требуется вмешательство модератора" поставить всё ещё можно.
Таким образом, обнаруженное поведение соответствует намерениям разработчиков. Подмены одной тревоги на другую не производилось.
Тем не менее в переводе имеется ошибка. Оригинальная строка:

You have retracted your recommended closure flag

Была переведена как:

Вы изменили тревогу «рекомендовано к закрытию»

Я изменил перевод, он будет доступен в новых версиях. Текущая 2024.5.24.9787. Новый перевод:

Вы отозвали тревогу с рекомендацией к закрытию


ошибки перевода, ок. я не обратила внимания на фразу под второй(мной отозванной/поставленой) тревогой, сейчас вижу это тот же текст.

получается, если я отозвала "дубликат", то я никогда не смогу поставить "Специфичная для сообщества причина" ?

@Dev18 да, именно так оно и работает.

за ваш ответ я проголосовала, тк он улучшит визуальную сторону сайта с переводом, благодарю за вклад, но я не согласна, что так задумано(поэтому не приняла), тк там разные причины все таки в корне(Специфичная причина и дубликат вот к примеру. пользователь ошибся, но надо же не "группу" вопросов удалять а "item" из группы, и таким образом группа остается доступной, а в самой группе item дубликат сделать красным=>я про группу "необходимо улучшить", в которой есть также дубликат). //а еще вопрос===>получается если я "отозвала" тревогу, я не смогу никогда на нее же поставить второй раз тревогу?

@Dev18 можно соглашаться, можно не соглашаться. Есть поведение, которое задумано быть на сайте и имплементировано разработчиками. Если оно работает как ожидается, то это [meta-tag:статус-так-задумано], если работает криво, то это валидный дефект, который должен пройти несколько стадий до [meta-tag:статус-завершено]. Отозванные тревоги нельзя взвести повторно, это тоже из разряда "так-задумано". Правильнее всего, проверить ситуацию на других сайтах. И если она везде работает одинаково, но это вызывает сомнение, то заводить пункт на MSE, а не на локальной Мете.

а вы уверенны, что обнаруженное поведение соответствует намерениям разработчиков, может просто упущен момент "удаление группы-удаление item" в коде

@Dev18 если всё ещё остаются сомнения, то предлагаю уточнить это на MSE. Вероятность того, что ответит действующий или бывших сотрудник компании, там заметно выше.

Нет сомнений, был вопрос вы уверены или это догадка

Догадка, что если это одна группа, то это нормально, что удаляется вся группа. Как раз сегодня у меня работа была над похожим алгоритмом и мы решили, что группа конечно одна, но удалять все не нужно и надо делать проверку, что item - дубликат не взят из группы, а взят из списка. В любом случае пусть повисит вопрос. Вам ещё раз спасибо за перевод
